# What Are Good Specific Reasons The onERC721Received Function Returns A Magic Value?

Tags: erc-721

The [ERC721 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) says the following:

> The onERC721Received function specifically works around old deployed contracts which may inadvertently return 1 (true) in certain circumstances even if they don't implement a function (see Solidity DelegateCallReturnValue bug). By returning and checking for a magic value, we are able to distinguish actual affirmative responses versus these vacuous trues.

This rationale says that there are certain circumstances where old contracts will inadvertently return 1 (true) even when they don't implement a function that is called.

The rationale gives the DelegateCallReturnValue bug as one of these circumstances. I would really like to know, what are the other circumstances?

In what circumstances will an old contract inadvertently return a wrong bool value when a method is called on it that does not exist?

Comment: I am citing research and notes from /chrisetha /axic and /arachnid. Hopefully they can provide more notes on the topic.